# How to find critical points of function with exp in matlab

Tags: matlab

Quick question, I hope someone can help me out here. I'm trying to find all critical points of the function:

```
f(x,y) = 0.05 * (1-12x+20x^2) * (1-7y+10y^2) * exp(-(x^2/6+y^2/3))
```

when I do the usual `fx = diff(f(x,y),x)` and `fy = diff(f(x,y),y)` then call `[xcr,ycr] = solve(fx,fy)` it only gives me one solution...I know there are more then that.

Could this be because there are an infinite number of solutions, and this is one? Is there a way around this?

thanks!

Comment: with surf(x,y,z)...can see there are 4 maximums, 4 saddles and maybe another between the four.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't share your exact code so I don't know what you did to get only one solution, but you can use the symbolic toolbox to solve this puppy:

```
% # Define the function f(x, y)
syms x y
f = 0.05 * (1 - 12*x + 20*x^2) * (1 - 7*y + 10*y^2) * exp(-(x^2 / 6 + y^2/3));

% # Find the partial derivatives
f_x = diff(f, x);
f_y = diff(f, y);

% # Find the critical points
[xcr, ycr] = solve(f_x, f_y);
p = double([xcr(:), ycr(:)]);

% # Discard the complex solutions
p(imag(p(:, 1)) > eps, :) = [];
p(imag(p(:, 2)) > eps, :) = [];
p = real(p);

xcr = p(:, 1)
ycr = p(:, 2)
```

This actually yields 13 solutions:

```
xcr =             ycr =

    0.5000            0.2000
    0.5000            0.5000
    0.1000            0.2000
    0.1000            0.5000
    2.6133            1.9238
   -2.3113            1.9238
    0.2980            1.9238
    2.6133           -1.5711
   -2.3113           -1.5711
    0.2980           -1.5711
    2.6133            0.3474
   -2.3113            0.3474
    0.2980            0.3474
```

Comment: Thanks EitanT for the reply, its more or less what I had...funny enough, when I run your code on my version of Matlab (7.11.0) all i get is xcr=0.1 and ycr = 0.2. None of the other solutions show. Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: No idea. I ran it on both on MATLAB R2009a (v7.8) and R2012a (v7.14) and I get the same results... Please insert `size(xcr)` and `size(ycr) after the line with `solve` and tell me what you get. Is it `[13 1]` for both of them.?

Comment: hhmmm weird. they are both [1 1]. Here is a screenshot https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8XEsIt0n6PeaVJPN2JCdHJBOW8

Comment: I'm stumped. Perhaps you can test this on another MATLAB workstation?

Comment: I've tried it on the two different versions i have access to (7.11.0 R2010b and 7.10.0.499 R2010b) and unfortunately they are both giving me the same results. Thanks for the help though, now that I know i have the code right I can take it up with Mathworks.