# How to find critical points of function - matlab

Tags: matlab, minimization

I know that this question was already posted by user1003131 and answered by Rody Oldenhuis in

[How to find critical points of function with exp in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300399/how-to-find-critical-points-of-function-with-exp-in-matlab)

The thing is that in the end EitanT is able to find several critical points and user1003131 finds only one.

The end of the discussion is inconclusive about why this happens. Any insights?

Also my code is as follows:

```
%% symbolic variables
syms w a l E I x;

%% equations
FIA=0;
THETAA=0;
MA=-((w*a)/(l^2))*((l-a)^2);
RA=(w/(l^3))*((l-a)^2)*(l+2*a);

%slope
HEAVISIDE_theta=(heaviside(x-a))*((x-a)^2);
theta=THETAA+((MA*x)/(E*I))+((RA*(x^2))/(2*E*I))-((w/(2*E*I))*HEAVISIDE_theta);

%deflection
HEAVISIDE_d=(heaviside(x-a))*((x-a)^3);
d=FIA+(THETAA*x)+((MA*(x^2))/(2*E*I))+((RA*(x^3))/(6*E*I))-((w/(6*E*I))*HEAVISIDE_d)

%% Partial differential equations
%slope
der_theta_x_2=(w*heaviside(x - a)*(2*a - 2*x))/(2*E*I) - (w*0*(a - x)^2)/(2*E*I) - (a*w*(a - l)^2)/(E*I*l^2) + (w*x*(a - l)^2*(2*a + l))/(E*I*l^3);
der_theta_a_2=(w*0*(a - x)^2)/(2*E*I) - (w*heaviside(x - a)*(2*a - 2*x))/(2*E*I) - (w*x*(a - l)^2)/(E*I*l^2) + (w*x^2*(a - l)^2)/(E*I*l^3) + (w*x^2*(2*a + l)*(2*a - 2*l))/(2*E*I*l^3) - (a*w*x*(2*a - 2*l))/(E*I*l^2);

%deflection
der_d_x_2=(w*0*(a - x)^3)/(6*E*I) - (w*heaviside(x - a)*(a - x)^2)/(2*E*I) + (w*x^2*(a - l)^2*(2*a + l))/(2*E*I*l^3) - (a*w*x*(a - l)^2)/(E*I*l^2);
der_d_a_2=(w*heaviside(x - a)*(a - x)^2)/(2*E*I) - (w*0*(a - x)^3)/(6*E*I) - (w*x^2*(a - l)^2)/(2*E*I*l^2) + (w*x^3*(a - l)^2)/(3*E*I*l^3) - (a*w*x^2*(2*a - 2*l))/(2*E*I*l^2) + (w*x^3*(2*a + l)*(2*a - 2*l))/(6*E*I*l^3);

%% define values
l=2;
I=4;
E=90000;
w=90;

%% replace symbols
theta=subs(theta);
d=subs(d);

der_theta_x_2=subs(der_theta_x_2);
der_theta_a_2=subs(der_theta_a_2);


der_d_x_2=subs(der_d_x_2);
der_d_a_2=subs(der_d_a_2);

%%   calculate critical points

[acr_theta, xcr_theta]=solve(der_theta_x_2, der_theta_a_2)
pcr_theta=double([acr_theta(:) xcr_theta(:)])


[acr_d, xcr_d]=solve(der_d_x_2==0,der_d_a_2==0, a, x)
pcr_d=double([acr_theta(:) xcr_theta(:)])
```

I would consider to find the extreme points by using minimization, but due to the presence of heaviside function I cannot do it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Hmm... so are you facing the same problem, or are you trying to resolve the inconsistency in the results of the previous question?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. from plotting the function d i can see a minima located at (1,1), but the result only shows the critical point (0,0)